# how to use the example of scrapy-redis

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have read the [example](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis) of scrapy-redis but still don't quite understand how to use it.

I have run the spider named dmoz and it works well. But when I start another spider named mycrawler_redis it just got nothing.

Besides I'm quite confused about how the request queue is set. I didn't find any piece of code in the example-project which illustrate the request queue setting.

And if the spiders on different machines want to share the same request queue, how can I get it done? It seems that I should firstly make the slave machine connect to the master machine's redis, but I'm not sure which part to put the relative code in,in the spider.py or I just type it in the command line?

I'm quite new to scrapy-redis and any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the example spider is working and your custom one isn't, there must be something that you have done wrong. Update your question with the code, including all relevant parts, so we can see what went wrong.

> Besides I'm quite confused about how the request queue is set. I
>   didn't find any piece of code in the example-project which illustrate
>   the request queue setting.

As far as your spider is concerned, this is done by appropriate project settings, for example if you want FIFO:

```
# Enables scheduling storing requests queue in redis.
SCHEDULER = "scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler"

# Don't cleanup redis queues, allows to pause/resume crawls.
SCHEDULER_PERSIST = True

# Schedule requests using a queue (FIFO).
SCHEDULER_QUEUE_CLASS = 'scrapy_redis.queue.SpiderQueue'
```

As far as the implementation goes, queuing is done via RedisSpider which you must inherit from your spider. You can find the code for enqueuing requests here: https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis/blob/a295b1854e3c3d1fddcd02ffd89ff30a6bea776f/scrapy_redis/scheduler.py#L73

As for the connection, you don't need to manually connect to the redis machine, you just specify the host and port information in the settings:

```
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
```

And the connection is configured in the `ċonnection.py`: https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis/blob/a295b1854e3c3d1fddcd02ffd89ff30a6bea776f/scrapy_redis/connection.py
The example of usage can be found in several places: https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis/blob/a295b1854e3c3d1fddcd02ffd89ff30a6bea776f/scrapy_redis/pipelines.py#L17

Comment: Lawrence,thank u sooooooooo much for your specific explanation! The problem was finally settled. I made a big mistake !!! I regarded the dmoz spider as the master spider which put the urls into the queue and missed the instruction about how to push urls to redis. TAT  So I kept looking for how the start_urls was conveyed to the slave spider like mycrawler and couldn't figure out how the spiders share the queue. Thanks a lot for your help !